# How should spec2017 set the compilation options?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking

I am compiling my spec2017. In my `config` directory, there is an `Example-gcc-linux-x86.cfg` file.
I copied it to a new file. I modified the `%define label` and `gcc` path.
I also saw a `config` file used by others. I compared it. I found that its config file is somewhat different from mine.

The main differences are:

1. There is one more sentence in his config file than mine:

   strict_rundir_verify = 0
2. Its compilation options are different from mine.

his is:

```
default=base:         # flags for all base
   OPTIMIZE       = -g -O2 -static -march=native -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations  -fno-tree-loop-vectorize
```

mine is:

```
default=base:         # flags for all base
   OPTIMIZE       = -g -O3 -static -march=native -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations  -fno-tree-loop-vectorize
```

I mainly use spec2017 for prefetching experiments, may I ask

1. What is the code that he added?
2. Which compile option is correct here?  If different compilation options are used between the papers, the results measured by spec2017 are not comparable? Then why these papers did not disclose the compilation rules of spec2017 they used?
3. Is it OK to compile spec2017 with the following command? Is it unnecessary to set up copies and threads in addition?

```
runcpu --config=Example-gcc-linux-x86-test.cfg --reportable --action=run al
```

Thanks!

Comment: `gcc -O3` enables auto-vectorization and a few other optimizations that `-O2` doesn't.  If code-cache footprint isn't a bottleneck (like most SPEC CPU benchmarks), it's often better.  (And sometimes still worth it for large programs on modern CPUs, if the hot loops that get vectorized or if-converted to branchless are important enough.)

Comment: I'm very much obliged to you! I mainly want to design a new prefetch algorithm and compare the performance with others. I would like to ask if the mainstream situation is -O2 or -O3? In this way, when comparing, it can be guaranteed that it is not the cause of the compiler option.

Comment: Official SPEC submissions include compiler options you can look at to see what most of them use.  http://spec.org/cpu2017/results/.  As far as other builds of other things, I think a lot of Linux distros still build their packages with only `-O2`.  (And of course not `-march=native` because they're building binaries to distribute.)